# How to run command as another user or keep file attributes?

Tags: sudo, chown

I run command:

```
find /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/2015/file.jpg | xargs /usr/local/bin/jpegoptim --max=90 --all-progressive --strip-all --strip-com --strip-exif -- strip-iptc --strip-icc
```

and then i have to:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/
```

To change back the ownership. How can I run the original command without changing file attributes?

Thanks,

Comment: I think `sudo username` does the part about running as another user, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Thanks Zacharee1 sudo -u www-data command worked for me :)

Comment: Should I post it as an answer?

Answer (score 5):

Putting `sudo -u username` before your command will solve your problem.

Comment: I think it was `sudo -u username`, yes?  just putting sudo somecommand produces "somecommand not found"